# how can i get current input value on change in Vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I want to get current select value without modeling on data.
in other words , I want get this select value in second method argument.
pay attention that this select placed in a v-for loop
how can i do this?

```
<select v-if="user.client_groups.length > 0" class="small" 
    @change="clientGroupChanged(user.id,???)">
         <option v-for="group in groups" :key="group.id" :value="group.id" 
         :selected="user.client_groups[0].id">{{ group.title }}</option>
</select>
```

and my clientGroupChanged method body is :

```
clientGroupChanged: function(uid,value){
            alert(value);
},
```

Answer (score 0):

the onchange wont get value from loop inside the select tag, you can get value from event such as

```
 <select
    v-if="user.client_groups.length > 0"
    class="small"
    @change="event => clientGroupChanged(user.id, event)"
  >
    <option
      v-for="group in groups"
      :key="group.id"
      :value="group.id"
      :selected="user.client_groups[0].id"
    >
      {{ group.title }}
    </option>
  </select>
```

your method should be like

```
clientGroupChanged(uid , event) {
      console.log(event.target.value);
}
```

remember: `event.target.value` will be id as the group as you are passing `group.id` to `key`

Answer (score 0):

Try this one, should be a working solution.

```
@change="(val) => clientGroupChanged(user.id, val)"
```

Comment: We don't have access to the value directly. We should get it from event.target.value.

Answer (score 0):

Well you should pass the value besides the uid to your change function like this:

```js
<select v-if="user.client_groups.length > 0" class="small" 
    @change="event => clientGroupChanged(user.id, event.target.value)">
         <option v-for="group in groups" :key="group.id" :value="group.id" 
         :selected="user.client_groups[0].id">{{ group.title }}</option>
</select>
```